# git extensions displays multiple "branches" even If i select only one

Tags: git, git-extensions

Even If I choose only one branch in git extensions it still shows me something like this. Why are there additional vertical lines? As I found out, red one is branch in my local repo, why is there a separate blue line with tags, why aren't they on red line?

Edit: and what are these circles and rectangles mean?

[image]

Comment: because other branches are merged into this one and not rebased.

Answer (score 1):

A git branch is basically a name that points to a commit, but the commit it points to is updated whenever a new commit is added to the branch.

Git is an acyclic directed graph. Each git commit has a) an optional [tree object](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/git-object-tree/), b) an optional parent commit (or two or more parents if it's a merge commit), and c) Commit metadata (committer name, email, commit message, etc.). This means that a branch, which in implementation is just a special auto-updated pointer to a commit, represents the entire subgraph accessible by traversing from that commit along its parents, and their parents, etc. In a history with no merges you will get what you expect; a single straight line of commits. In a history with merges you will see what you have here, multiple paths expanding outward (and merging inwards when a commit started two separate branches which were later merged together.

Comment: Technically each commit has a *tree*, not a change-set.  The change-set is computed dynamically: use commit to get tree, use commit-parent (or anything really) to get another tree, diff the two trees.  This is not so important for a single-parent commit but for multi-parent (merge) commits this technical point starts to matter more. :-)  And in fact, git supports "octopus" (3 or more parent) commits.

Answer (score 0):

And for your edit:
The circles represent revisions in the history.
The squares represent a revision which is referenced by one ore more branches.

Comment: Yes, could be tags **as well**.

Comment: Confirmed in the GitExtensions source code:  the square is drawn whenever there is a "Git Reference" pointing to that commit (called a "revision" in the source code).  This is covered under the topic of Git References [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References).  In short: both branches and tags.  At a glance in the GitExtensions source code it does not appear to include remote references in the criteria to draw a square (but I could be wrong, as I've run out of time to investigate it).